# How to link html pages together on winscp

Tags: html

How do I link two html files together on winscp?I am working by connecting to my college linux server and running the website on the server. I'm very new to html, so this might be a dumb question, but I cant get it to work. I have a homepage page here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>.</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="height:1500px">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <br>
    <h3>Welcome to my website!</h3>
    <p>Here I will share with you my interests</p>
    <p>Scroll down and enjoy!</p>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.mywebsite.com">Home</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.google.ie/">Google</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid"><br>
    <p>Click on Home to go to the homepage, which is the homepage</p>
    <p>Click on Google in the nav bar to go to www.google.com</p>
    <p>Click on Login to go to the login screen</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And I have a login page that is linked from the nav bar on the homepage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

When I click on login in the nav bar, I want the browser to go to the login page. On the server, login.hbs(the login page) and layout.hbs(the homepage) are both in the same folder. How do I do this? I tried using href="login.hbs" and many other ways for href but I cannot get it to work. All I get is 404 errors. What do I do?

Comment: WinSCP is a tool for copying files between computers. It has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I don't see what WinSCP has to do with this. The link in your homepage goes to `login.html`, so what's `login.hbs`?

Comment: HBS is a template language commonly used by applications written using the Express.js library for Node.js. You need to find out how your server side code is handling URLs and what that has to do with the template files you are creating.